linux, different form of an arithmetic operation
I execute the following bash commands
1- y=$((x+1))
2- y=$((x++))

but I get different results for y. suppose x=7. in case 1, (y=8, x=7), but in case 2 (x=8, y=7)
I don't know why?
I am using bash version 5.1.16

Use y=$((x ++)).

My question is, why?

@Cyrus, on bash 4.4 your idea give the same result

So, is it wrong or something else?

@tahzibi.jafar, IMHO space before ++ does not matter (in bash, in $((   )) construction)

Because the first operation do:
add 1 to x and then assign the result to y
the second operation do:
assign x to y and then increace the value of x (the ++ is after the x)
